# unjoin sprinkles on donut

Tags: parent

Since everyone is familiar with the dount tutorial, I can just refer to the problem using that example. The sprinkles are a part of the icing. How can I unjoin the sprinkles from the icing? The P/unjoin loose parts doesn't work as nothing seems to be loose or joined previously. They are made/multiplied with nodes so I suspect the solution is somewhere there... Hope I explained it well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Everyone is **not** familiar with the donut tutorial as it was made for beginners and most people here are certainly not beginners!

Comment: Is this the donut tutorial for Blender 3 (https://youtu.be/nIoXOplUvAw)? A link would be helpful. The sprinkles are probably made with Geometry Nodes. So you have to apply the modifier but make a backup first. Then you have lots of sprinkles. Maybe elaborate more on what you want to do with the sprinkles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who helped. So to answer my question it is: "make instances real" once the instances are selected and you click the modifier button. They become a mesh.